# How do I get my current location in Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, null, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating an app where the user needs to see his/her geo location with getMyLocation(), but this is returning null. Is there any solution for this, because I did read that the getMyLocation() method is always returning null. I'm new to Google Maps, so any help will be appreciated!

Code:

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();

if( myLocation != null ){
    helper.showToast( "Latitude: " + myLocation.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + myLocation.getLongitude() );
}
```

Comment: Add some code. How should we guess what you do wrong?

Comment: http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/2013/09/showing-current-location-in-google-maps.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the sample code of the `Google Maps Android API v2` , Using this you will solve your problem.

[Sample Code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java)

Comment: I don't see any solution at the link you provide. Please explain what you want to show me?

Comment: install `google-play-services` into your sdk manager.if already installed then open your sdk folder and follw this steps `<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps` you got the sample code.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I saw some nice examples and I will accept your answer, because this definitely helped me out!

Comment: What was the actual problem? how did you fix it? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @publicstaticvoid   after installed  `google-play-services`  , go to  `\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps` in your sdk. you can see example here

Answer (score 14):

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {


             mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
           }
          });

            }
        }
    }
```

call this function in on create function

Comment: where you getting stuck tell me ?

Comment: Well it was not working to find my current location. but i achieved this by using Location manager class.

Comment: This is working code. Just use Location arg0 as your curret (not null) Location !

Answer (score 4):

I don't like new google maps API because of their limited and defects. In your case I think the best way is to use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) classes. You'll get location, when your phone will find satellites and then you can add the marker on the map. Also you can use [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) method if you need to get location quickly. I think google maps `getMyLocation()` method return null because the phone don't have much time to know it's location, when app starts up. And in Google Maps API v2 there is no some kind of `onLocationChanged()` method. I don't like this API.

Answer (score 1):

`map.getMyLocation() return null` becouse there is no location on `onCreate();`

the first time the map get position is after the first onCameraChange() event.

so use

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener( new ...)
```

on your map and do your implementation after the first time occurred

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way:

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
```

on **onCreate()**:

```
mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mGoogleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

Now add **MyLocationChangeListener**:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Latitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+" - Longitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
   }
};
```

Hope this will help you.